# Powershell Join

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have an AD query to export all groups membership, that works perfectly.

```
Get-QADUser -searchRoot $OuDomain -SizeLimit 0 
| Select-Object dn, sAMAccountName, @{Name="Groups";Expression={(Get-QADMemberOf $_ 
| Select-Object -expandProperty Name) -join ";"}} 
| export-csv $FilePath | Sort-Object SamAccountName
```

Result :

```
DN        SamAccountName    Groups
abc.com   user1             group1;group2;group3
```

How to export the above results in columns, like :

```
DN       SamAccountName  Groups
abc.com  user1           group1
         user1           group2
         user1           group3
```

Please check http://pastebin.com/JMZ863YY

Comment: Thanks Seki for the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the -join, whose purpose is to keep one (user) to many (group) record, you'll need to do something like this (untested). Give it a try:

```
$users = Get-QADUser -searchRoot $OuDomain -SizeLimit 0
$users | Sort-Object SamAccountName | % {
    $user = $_ | Select-Object dn, sAMAccountName
    if ($lastDomain -eq $user.dn) {
        $lastDomain = ""
    } else {
        $lastDomain = $user.dn
    }
    $groups = Get-QADMemberOf $_ | Select-Object -expandProperty Name
    $groups | % {
        $user2 = New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{
                "Domain" = $lastDomain
                "sAMAccountName" = $user.sAMAccountName
                "Group" = $_
            } 
        $user2
    }
} | export-csv $FilePath
```

Comment: Hi Andy, I am getting error message "Get-QADMemberOf : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "@{DN=CN=test,OU=test1,OU=test,OU=abc,DC=xyz,DC=com; Sam
AccountName=k201293}" value of type "Selected.Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Data.ArsUserObject" to type "Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShell
SnapIn.Data.IdentityParameter"."

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks a lot , The output which I received is perfect , it's throwing lots of error message I have more than 20000 thousands users. Please see http://pastebin.com/rS5CLR3b

Comment: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown , how to rectify this error

Comment: @Naveenk It's because of the way the pipeline is buffering things in memory, due to the pipe to `export-csv`. I actually created a test AD with 20K users to try it out and I saw the issue. I might be able to take a look soon.